# Polymorphism implement forced common alterations to child's fields

Tags: java, kotlin, design-patterns, polymorphism

What's the best design pattern to force children of an abstract class to call a function defined in the abstract class that alters the value of its implemented abstract variables?

***The problem:***

I want to scale my bitmaps according to the screen size to keep the ratio. I want to avoid having multiple abstract variables that are essentially assigned the same way. For example in this case `widthScale * width` will scale the width when assigned to the width. If I create an abstract method named scaleWidth(), though it would imply to the user of the class that they should implement such functionality, it'd cause a repetitious implementation of the same method throughout the codebase.

Also can't have a scaledWidth variable in the abstract class that multiplies 2 abstract variables since parent's fields are initialized before the childrens'

***Pseudocode example:***

```
Abstract Class Image
{
  abstract int width;

}

Class Apple extends Image
{
  override int width = 100 * StaticAppClass.scaleFactorWidth;

}

Class Banana extends Image
{
  override int width = 50 * StaticAppClass.scaleFactorWidth;
}
```

So as you can see every time the programmer has to multiply the width with the StaticAppClass.scaleFactorWidth. Not only it's inconvenient also it's not explicit. Meaning, the programmer wouldn't even know he has to do that

Comment: Sorry, you need to flesh this out with a code sample showing your current approach and explain clearly what you want to do differently.  There's not enough information yet for the question to be answerable.

Comment: @JimGarrison Added pseudocode, hope it explains the problem I am trying to address

Comment: The idea that you could or would *force* subclasses to do things a certain way is probably ill-conceived.  Instead, it would be appropriate to document how subclasses *should* do things, and to provide methods, whether abstract or concrete, that support and guide subclass implementation.  I think you'll find that "How can I help subclasses do it right?" is an easier question to answer than "How can I prevent subclasses from doing it wrong?".

Comment: @JohnBollinger Interesting recommendation. I've always thought it must be as obvious as possible for the programmers to use the class correctly, therefore, one should restrict the wrong implementations. Do you think being dependent on the documents and not the code itself is a good approach?

Comment: @Mustafa, I did not say that that code had no role to play. In fact, I specifically said that it would be appropriate to provide methods that support and guide subclass implementation.  But if you write classes that can usefully be extended at all then there is no way to prevent people from doing it wrongly (for some sense of the word "wrong").  And who knows? Some extensions that do things differently than you anticipate may nevertheless be consistent and useful.

Comment: Designing and documenting for extension is hard, but the core ideas are similar to those involved in designing and documenting for direct use.  In fact, to a large degree, the former is an extension of the latter.  Not only do extenders need to know each method's individual contract, they also need to know how non-`final` methods are used by other methods of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just have the subclasses assign their width values, and have the superclass implement a `scaledWidth` getter? (You said Kotlin and I'm in Kotlin mode so here's my example!)

```
abstract class Image {
    abstract val width: Int
    val scaleFactorWidth = 2
    fun getScaledWidth() = width * scaleFactorWidth
}

class Banana : Image() {
    override val width = 100
}
```

that way the only thing the subclasses need to implement is a `width` property (I mean it would be better to pass them into the constructor but there might be too many properties for that). The scaled width is accessed through a getter function, so it's all initialised by the time anyone calls it.

If you are in Kotlin you could even do

```
val scaledWidth by lazy { width * scaledWidth }
```

which stores a single value, but calculates it (once) when it's first accessed - so long as that's not during the initialisation of the `Image` superclass, you should be ok?

Comment: This was my initial approach to it -using lazy properties- the problem however is I use the scaledWidth in the abstract class for initializing other fields. Kotlin is smart enough to give a warning that the width at that moment is not yet assigned and it might change therefore it gave errors when I ran it

Comment: Yeah you'd need to make those lazy too, so the initialisation basically gets triggered when one of the properties is accessed. Honestly, if that's a bit unwieldy, I feel like passing stuff into the constructor is the way to go - that way the class has all the info it needs during the intialisation stage. If you don't want too many parameters, how about making a config data class or something? Then you can pass that in as a single parameter, and it can contain things like the subclass's width and height etc

Comment: Already have a config class for a different part of the same class but it would be inappropriate to add it to there. Could use a Kotlin Pair class but as we were discussing the dependency injection alternative at the above answer I have come to realize it would only cause a more complex architecture... All those interfaces all around only to pass a variable. 
Making the other fields lazy is the way to go for this. Thanks for the answer, I don't know why I didn't realize that was an option.

Comment: Okay, I was gonna accept your answer but wanted to try it out first. So have been restructuring my code to get it to compile first. Here is the thing, making other fields initialized by lazy doesn't work. It uses the value 0 when initializing an Int. Therefore I am getting an arithmetic exception: can't divide by zero... 

  val scaledWidth by lazy{(width * scaleFactorX).toInt()}
    val scaledHeight by lazy{(width * scaleFactorY).toInt()}
    val scaledFrameWidth by lazy { (scaledWidth / frameCount)}
    val scaledFrameHeight by lazy { scaledHeight / rowCount }

Comment: It seems to work ok? https://pl.kotl.in/28sT0HwOb You have to make sure that none of those lazy values are being evaluated during construction, before the values they reference are initialised. At an extreme, you'd have every value that depends on another value be lazy (so none of those dependencies are followed until some user of the class tries to access one of them, long after it's all set up)  - but you can probably get away with only doing it on some stuff (like in my linked example where ``Banana`` has a property that depends on a lazy value, but ``Image`` is already initialised enough)

Comment: Apparently, the problem was the overriding order of the field of child classes. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Binding to member fields happens at compile time, so there's no way to directly do what you want.  I.e. there's no `@Override` for fields. I believe the best way is as follows:

```
public static final int scaleFactor = 10;

public abstract class A
{
    public int getScaledWidth()
    {
        return this.getWidth() * scaleFactor;
    }
    public abstract int getWidth();
}

public class B extends A
{
    public int width = 50;
    @Override
    public int getWidth() { return width; }
}

public class C extends A
{
    public int width = 100;
    @Override
    public int getWidth() { return width; }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.getScaledWidth());
    C c = new C();
    System.out.println(c.getScaledWidth());
}
```

With this structure, when writing a new specialization of `A`, the developer will be required to provide `getWidth()`, forcing them to consider what is needed.

Comment: Having coded only in Kotlin for a year I totally forgot overriding fields wasn't a thing in Java. I wanted to avoid turning getScaledWidth into a function since it's being used so often and therefore adding unnecessary CPU cycles. But whilst keeping the width variable I can use lazy properties of kotlin I suppose. Thanks for your answer

Comment: If `width` is a class constant, meaning the scaled width is also constant, you could calculate it once in a static initializer and just return the value.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Though it's depended on the scaleFactor which is being an invisible dependency and might cause problems depending on the assignment order of these statics. That won't be a problem in my program in the foreseeable future but do you think it's a good practice to write it that way?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the cost of calculating it. If the scale factor could change from run to run, make it a constructor parameter, or an injected value if using Spring.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps dependency injection would be the best approach. It will add some boilerplate code which is ironically what it suppose to help with but whatever.  I have a feeling OOP won't be the norm in the next decade but rather we will have different styles of programming for different areas of the project

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, width is a constant different for each implementation?

I would do something like that:

In the abstract class:

```
public abstract int getWidth();
```

In the implementations:

```
@Override
public int getWidth() {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question but thank you for taking the time to write an answer.